# NVidia DIGITS DetectNet alternatives

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, caffe, object-detection, nvidia-digits

I am looking for detection/localization CNNs to run within the NVidia DIGITS training platform.  So far it seems they only support their homebrew DetectNet for this purpose.  Looking around it seems that other SOTA networks such as faster-RCNN, SSD, and YOLO might compete with DetectNet in terms of performance and accuracy, but it does not look like they currently have any support in DIGITS.  (Faster-RCNN has a [fairly popular implementation](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn), but it is run out of a version of  Caffe not supported by DIGITS.)

If anyone has had any success obtaining and using SOTA detection networks with NVidia DIGITS, would you mind supplying links/documentation regarding?

Comment: With all due respect, is that relevant to the question?  I don't need to use DIGITS, but if somehow it is possible I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, NVIDIA provides NVIDIA Transfer Learning Toolkit which is useful for training CNNs. NVIDIA provides SSD, Faster RCNN, DetectNet, etc. You can find more here: https://developer.nvidia.com/transfer-learning-toolkit